# how to get a content of a file to event log

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have got PS script to get the Regkey count to a text file. I am using this script in Task Scheduler & Can you please let me know if we can get the content of that file and have that logged to event viewer once the task is ran? Script is mentioned below -

```
if (!([diagnostics.process]::GetCurrentProcess().Path -match '\\syswow64\\'))
{
$uninstallPath = "\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
$uninstallWow6432Path = "\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
@(
if (Test-Path "HKLM:$uninstallWow6432Path" ) {Get-ChildItem "HKLM:$uninstallWow6432Path"-Recurse | Measure-Object | Out-File "C:\PS Output\Total6432.txt"}
if (Test-Path "HKLM:$uninstallpath" ) {Get-ChildItem "HKLM:$UninstallPath" -Recurse | Measure-Object | Out-File "C:\PS Output\Total32.txt"}
)
}
```

---

I tried the following code mentioned below and I couldnt see anything written in the Event Viewer. Can you please give me some guidance in this??

```
if (!([diagnostics.process]::GetCurrentProcess().Path -match '\\syswow64\\'))
{
  $uninstallPath = "\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
  $uninstallWow6432Path = "\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion  \Uninstall\"
  @(
  if (Test-Path "HKLM:$uninstallWow6432Path" ) {Get-ChildItem "HKLM:$uninstallWow6432Path"-Recurse | Measure-Object | Out-File "C:\PS Output\Total6432.txt"}
  if (Test-Path "HKLM:$uninstallpath" ) {Get-ChildItem "HKLM:$UninstallPath" -Recurse | Measure-Object | Out-File "C:\PS Output\Total32.txt"}
)

$Content = Get-content -Path 'C:\PS Output\Total6432.txt'
$Content1 = Get-Content -Path 'C:\PS Output\Total32.txt'
{
Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source $Content AND $Content1 -EventId 3001 -EntryType Information "Count is Registered"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply read the contents of the file and use a command like `write-eventlog` to write to a particular event log at the end of your script? What problems do you encounter?

Take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davethompson/archive/2011/10/25/running-a-scheduled-task-after-another.aspx for information on running one task after another, you could then create such a second task which simply reads the files above and writes them to an event log.

If this doesn't answer your question, what exactly are you having trouble with?